# Why is this PUT request behaving like a PATCH?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm working in this app with Django and DRF in the backend, and I'm having a problem with a certain endpoint.

When making a `PUT` request to `/api/v1/expenses/:id`, if I modify the `client` or `provider` fields, as long as there is at least one `client` or `provider`, there is no problem, they can be modified all right. The request payload would look like this:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": 2,
  "provider": 4,
  "client": 6,
  "attachments": "[]",
  "tax": 1,
  "cost": "200.00",
  "withholding": "0.00",
  "total_cost": "242.00",
  "date": "2021-2-11",
  "description": "Factura luz sede",
  "created": "2021-02-11T13:51:33.218081Z",
  "updated": "2021-03-19T14:45:05.322533Z",
  "creator": 1
}
```

However, if I leave the `provider` or `client` fields empty, and they aren't present in the request payload, they're not emptied, the response would still return whatever `provider` and/or `client` were there before. If I understand the `PUT` HTTP verb correctly, it should replace the resource with what's provided, right?

Here is an example request to illustrate what I mean:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": 2,
  "attachments": "[]",
  "tax": 1,
  "cost": "200.00",
  "withholding": "0.00",
  "total_cost": "242.00",
  "date": "2021-2-11",
  "description": "Factura luz sede",
  "created": "2021-02-11T13:51:33.218081Z",
  "updated": "2021-03-19T14:43:31.780350Z",
  "creator": 1
}
```

The model, stripped down to the problematic fields:

```py
class Expense(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey('contacts.Contact', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="expenses", null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey('contacts.Contact', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="client_expenses", null=True)
```

The serializer, again, stripped down:

```py
class ExpenseWriteSerializer(CustomWriteSerializer):
    provider = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    client = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    def validate_provider(self, value):
        return contact_models.Contact.objects.using(self.context['db']).get(id=value)

    def validate_client(self, value):
        return contact_models.Contact.objects.using(self.context['db']).get(id=value)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Expense
        fields = '__all__'
```

And the viewset:

```py
class ExpenseViewSet(CustomViewSet):
    model = models.Expense
    read_serializer_class = serializers.ExpenseReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = serializers.ExpenseWriteSerializer
    model_name = 'expense'
```

`update()` method in the `CustomViewSet`

```py
def update(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
        """
        Update Instance
        """
        try:
            partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
            instance = self.get_custom_queryset(request).filter(id=pk)
            core_user = User.objects.using(request.user.db).filter(email=request.user.email).first()

            serializer = self.write_serializer_class(
                data=request.data,
                partial=partial,
                context={"db": request.user.db, "core_user": core_user},
            )
            if serializer.is_valid():
                # extract many to many data
                tags = serializer.validated_data.pop('tags', None)
                attachments = serializer.validated_data.pop('attachments', None)
                # update values
                instance.update(**serializer.validated_data)
                instance.first().save()
                if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
                    # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
                    # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
                    instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}
                # save many2many data
                if tags:
                    # delete all current tags to avoid duplications
                    instance.first().tags.set([])
                    # iterate and add
                    for tag_id in tags:
                        tag = Tag.objects.using(request.user.db).filter(pk=tag_id).first()
                        instance.first().tags.add(tag)
                if attachments:
                    # delete all current legal_files to avoid duplications
                    instance.first().attachments.set([])
                    # iterate and add
                    for attachment_id in attachments:
                        attachment = base_models.Attachment.objects.using(request.user.db).filter(
                            pk=attachment_id).first()
                        instance.first().attachments.add(attachment)

                instance.first().save(using=request.user.db, update_fields=['created'])

                return Response(self.read_serializer_class(instance[0], many=False).data)
            else:
                # No correct data passed (TODO: Register log?)
                return Response(
                    serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

        except Exception as e:
            # TODO: Unknown error, must be logged
            return Response(
                str(e), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is in your update custom method. As you can see in the standard DRF Libraries:

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
          <
          ...
          ...
          >

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

He is using serializer instance to update the instance, passing partial argument as True makes the difference between PUT and PATCH. Since you are not using serializer instance to update the model object partial is not making anything different when you pass it to the serializer class.

I can't reproduce your code since it has a lot of custom methods, but as your not using save method in the serializer to update the instance, the logic of deleting previous fields if you want to override them it's on your side.

If I'm not wrong here is the logic where fields on subject should be overriden:

```
                instance.update(**serializer.validated_data)
                instance.first().save()
```

There's no mention wether to delete all fields or not based on partial argument. Here is where you should implement your logic to set to null all fields not present in request.

My recommendation is first to check what are you getting on `serializer.validated_data` to see if your getting `None` in the fields you want to override. When you got clear what are you getting try write the logic to perform differently in PUT and PATCH methods.

My second recommendation is that you try to refactor the method to be as similar as DRF as possible, modifying only strictly necessary parts. As you can see django is passing to the serializer not the request data but the instance and then the data to update. This makes sense since you want to update your instance with new provided data. Making this not only will allow future development easier to read and maintain, but it will help you understand the way django works.